# Load mix of local images and server data in Webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, image-loading

I have a webview contain Listview displays Posts data like Name, Image, Price etc. These post images are fixed. Total 10 type of posts hava 10 different fixed images. Images taking much time to load so i need to load images from local drawable folder and data from server as earlier.
I seen some ways as below, but none of them worked well. I want images to load in webview without uploading to server. Please let me know if any way to do this with less loading time.

```
1) webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/image.jpg");  // Loading only local image
2) webView.loadUrl("javascript:uploadImages(" + jobj + ")");  // Much Upload and load times
```

Answer (score 0):

Please store your all images in drawable and you can setImage after that:

```
holder.imgVIew.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_wedding_apps));
```

And While you have set a image to ImageView Hide the WebView..

I hope you got my point

Comment: But I want to load these images in Listview which is inside Webview. I don't want to change remaining data in webview.

Comment: from where you are getting webview data

Comment: Webview loading my own jsp page, data getting from my app's sql server.

Comment: In this case you need to send image data through jsp page only.. because webview is a single entity you can't modify..